R Markdown Title and Table formatting for Word output
I have to make a word output from R Markdown.
How can I separate words in the title of the R Markdown document so the first two words are in the first line, the third word is in the second line (with an empty row between the first line and the second line of the title), and the fourth word is below the third word (in the next line) in the Word output document?
Also, my table is shown without borders in the Word output document. Is it possible to fix that?
I'm using TinyTex, since I had some troubles during the installation of MikTex (for Windows). Can that be the reason for not showing the borders for the tables?
This is my R Markdown code in RStudio:
---
title: "Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4"
output: word_document
date: "2024-08-06"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}





Col1
Col2
Col3




11
21
31


21
22
32


31
23
33




